# Incorrect string value '\xF1ez' to MySQL utf8mb4 server

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am populating a new MySQL database. The server uses **utf8mb4** and **utf8mb4_unicode_ci** but the sql (database tables) to be imported are a mix of **latin1** and **utf8**. Upon inspection the issue was the letter **ñ**. I am thinking to manually change the enye to letter **n** but this would take up some time to finish

Comment: You will probably have to convert your input SQL, then use it. You may need a conversion tool to achieve this, but there are many to choose from. Make sure your connection is `utf8mb4` to match.

Answer (score 0):

Does a single column in a single table have a mixture of hex `F1` and `C3B1` for `ñ`?  If so, there is no easy way to deal with it.  If, on the other hand, one column uses latin1 encoding and another uses utf8, then simply specify each column according to the encoding needed.

But... If there is a *single* client writing F1 and C3B1 intermixed, then you really need to fix the data in the client.  Or you could store into `BINARY` or `BLOB` columns, then use SQL to fix things.  But that, too, would be messy.

`F1` is latin1.  If *all* accented characters in the client are single-byte things like that, not UTF-8 encodings, then specify "latin1" on the *connection* parameters.  With this, all the problems may be solved.